# How do you monitor another application until it closes?

Tags: c#-4.0

Suppose there are two executables. One is mine and the other is some other application.  Now if the other app is running, I want my app to run until the other one exits or is stopped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Writing a separate service seems quite an overkill.

You can first obtain a Process object - say by Process.GetProcessesByName, or better - use  the ProcessID of the process you wish to monitor, if you have it.  You can then try obtaining a WaitHandle from it, as discussed [e.g. here](http://www.codeguru.com/forum/showthread.php?t=466382), then call WaitOne on it (or WaitAll, if you're monitoring several instances).

Answer (score 2):

Write a windows service that will continuously monitor the `other` application executable. If the service finds it running it will start your executable if not running and make sure it keeps running throughout the life cycle of the `other` application. As soon as the `other` app terminates, your windows service will also terminate your exe.